# I get the following error and I am using Android studio 3.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get the following error and I am using Android studio 3.1

> Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

[Here's the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsFFe.jpg).
When adding components to the screen in design mode, they are not displayed there

[Here's how to look my Gradle Scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEDMK.jpg)

Comment: You should change your Grandle Script/error/code image for text

Comment: Why are you using alpha versions? Where did you get that error message from? Because it's not in the those images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem accour by using `api 28`. Downgrade to `26` and use as follow

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Why 26 instead of 27?

Comment: If it fails to load a class, that's a dependency problem, not an SDK version issue, though